# Report dataset ending refreshing time PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am wondering if we can report the ending dataset refreshing time in the powerBI report. I googled and found some useful tips to add last refreshing time (starting refreshing time) in the report. However, I need my clients to know if the report is refreshed, so the ending dataset refreshing time provides more info for my case.

[image]
Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what "beginning dataset" and "ending dataset" mean in this context?

Comment: Hi Alexis, Ya I add more info in the post. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can include the end time within the report itself but, for me, you can see that information at the top of the report page when you expand the Data updated dropdown.

[image: Data updated timestamp]

(This is in the online service at [https://app.powerbi.com](https://app.powerbi.com/).)